# Three approaches to design conditional instructions

Tags: assembly, x86

I've seen a one picture presenting 3 approaches  to desing conditional instruction. It looks like:

```
1. One step:
bz s1, label ; branch if s1 = 0
jecxa label  ; branch if ecx = 0
2. Two steps with tags:
CP A, 0         ; set flags
JR Z, MULEND    ; jump if Z = 1

cmp eax, 0      ; set flags
jz mulend       ; jump if zf = 1

3. Two step with predicates:
cmp.eq p1, p2 = r1, r2   ; if r1=r2
(p1) add r3 = 1, r3      ; then r3 := r3  +1
(p2) add r3 = 3, r3      ; else r3 := r3 + 3
```

And I don't what's going on. I could search in google but I cannot find anything. If someone knows what is it, please reference me to somewhere.

---

I would like to compare those free ways of controlling a flow of the program:
So:

```
Advantages:
1. There is no data-dependency ( flag register)
2. None? 
3. There is less branch instruction in implementation of if-then-else
Disadvantages:
1. None?
2. There is data-dependency ( flag register)
3. Data-dependency of registers for the true-predicate and the false-predicate
```

Please mark it and say something else.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There is no question. I am asking for helping me find more information about that post.  I tried searching on my own but without a success. Probably terms used on the slide are "specific" for specific language and it makes a problem with googling it.

Comment: Sorry. This site is for specific programming questions about a problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of other information do you want?  I was going to post this as a comment, but it might work as an answer.

---

The predicate version looks pretty weird to me, but that's probably because I'm used to seeing predicated instructions just use the flags as inputs.

And it seems really weird for `cmp` to produce two separate results, inverse of each other.  Is that really easier than letting instructions use the inverse of a predicate?  (2-result cmp vs. an extra bit in the encoding of every predicated instruction)

---

Other than that, everything looks really obvious and straightforward, if you've seen x86.  IIRC, MIPS is more like the "One step" version, since instead of a FLAGS register, its compare instructions use GP registers as outputs.